# Checkboxes check on button Click

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a list view of check boxes in which first checkbox is checked and in footer i have next button if user click on next button then the next checkbox is check in 2nd row is checked. And if again press next then third is checked. Please help i am stuck in that so long. Thank you.

```
  public class PlanetArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<Boolean> positionArray;
    Context ctx;

    public PlanetArrayAdapter( Context context, List<Planet> planetList ) {
        super( context, R.layout.list_rowss, R.id.rowTextView, planetList );
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) ;
        positionArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>(planetList.size());
        for(int i =0;i<planetList.size();i++){
            positionArray.add(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       position_new =position;
        Planet planet = (Planet) this.getItem( position_new );      
        final CheckBox checkBox ;
        final TextView textView,textview_duration_MAX, textview_duration_Current;
        final CheckBox pauseplay; ;

        final ImageView download,fb,twitter,add;
        final SeekBar pb;

        if ( convertView == null ) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rowss, null);


            textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.rowTextView );

            checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById( R.id.CheckBox01 );
            pb = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
            pauseplay = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            textview_duration_MAX = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            textview_duration_Current =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            download = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            fb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            twitter = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            add = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);

            checkBox.setTag(position);

            // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't have to
            // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.
            convertView.setTag( new PlanetViewHolder(textView,textview_duration_MAX,textview_duration_Current,checkBox,pb,pauseplay,add) );



            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    Planet palnts = (Planet) buttonView.getTag();


                    Log.d("poiuy",palnts+"");//For getting checkbox postion


                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) buttonView;

                    Planet planet = (Planet) cb.getTag();
                    planet.setChecked(cb.isChecked());

                    boolean isStart;

                    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {


                        if (selected != null) {
                            selected.setChecked(false);
                        }

                        checkBox.setChecked(true);
                        selected = checkBox;

                        pauseplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        song_namef.setText(planet.getName().substring(18));
                        playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pausef);

                        View parentRow = (View) buttonView.getParent();
                        ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
                         positiono = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);
                        mPlayingPosition = positiono;

                        final Runnable mUpdateTime = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                int currentDuration;
                                int totalduration;
                                if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                    currentDuration = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                                    totalduration = mPlayer.getDuration();
                                    textview_duration_MAX.setText("" + milliSecondsToTimer((long) totalduration));
                                    textview_duration_Current.setText("" + milliSecondsToTimer((long) currentDuration));
                                    textview_duration_Current.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                                } else {
                                    textview_duration_Current.removeCallbacks(this);
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        isStart = false;
                        //   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"positiono"+positiono,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("OnlyPosssssd", String.valueOf(mPlayingPosition));


                        try {
                            mPlayer.reset();
                            mPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(planet = listAdapter.getItem(mPlayingPosition)));

                            mPlayer.prepare();
                            mPlayer.start();
                            mPlayingPosition = positiono;
                            // Log.d("OnlyPos", String.valueOf(mPlayingPosition));


                            pb.setProgress(0);
                            pb.setMax(100);


                            seekbarf.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());

                            updatePosition();

                            isStarted = true;
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mProgressUpdater, 500);

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                      );}


            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Next",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    itemPosition = itemPosition+1;
                    next(itemPosition);
                    playSong(itemPosition);
                    if (view != null) {
                        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
                        checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());

                    }
                }
            });

    public  void next(int next){

    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 next, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    parents.getChildAt(next).setBackground(getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.backpause));

    if (save != -1 && save != next){
        parents.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);      
    }
    save = next;

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: We ll help you, but you have to show what you did yet, and what is not working :)

Comment: Code Updated !! guyz :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have setChecked method already in your Planet class, best would be you keep the track of last clicked index and on every next button click increment it. Then get the planet item from the list of items at that index, setChecked(true) or false based on the getChecked() result and then call adapter.notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: where you have defined the method next(itemPosition);?

Comment: below the return view.

Comment: Bro. i have i a list if click on first row then the checkboxes and next button appear.Now i want if i press next the second row list is clicked and perform its actions.